# Where do you store an airplane for an overnight stop?

Tags: general-aviation, aircraft-storing

When a private pilot flies a plane like a Cessna 172 on a two-or-more-day trip, where do they store the plane during overnight stops?

Comment: Reminds me of a dad joke: **Q:** Where does an airplane sleep?  **A:** AirBnb  -- *I'll be here all week... please tip your waitresses kindly.*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Most small airports have places for transient aircraft parking.  Sometimes they are paved and have tiedown spots, other times is might be a grass field.  Prepared pilots may bring their own tie down anchors if windy conditions are anticipated.

Larger airports often have Fixed Base Operators (FBOs) who will host you, providing tiedowns, maybe hangar space, fuel, snacks, a lounge, areas for flight planning, etc.  Sometimes a courtesy car is even available.

Comment: Some FBOs have hangars and, for an additional charge, will let transients park there overnight.

Comment: I'm sure that, for the right price, one could find hangar space just about anywhere that has hangars. Probably wouldn't be worth that "right price", though.

Comment: Usually on the apron.  e.g.: See [Apron parking fees (for my local airport)](https://www.waterlooairport.ca/en/business/rates-and-fees.aspx#Apron_Parking)

Comment: It never hurts to ask if the FBO has a hangar available for overnight rent! As an example, on my first solo cross country, the return flight had to be delayed 2 days after a dying battery delayed departure to the point unfavorable weather conditions began to develop. With thunderstorms forming, I paid $10/night for a hangar at KRLD - *very* cheap insurance compared to hail damage.

Comment: I do a lot of business trips and I always follow the same pattern...  (a) Check out the airport ramp layout on google  maps aerial images.  (b) Look in the AFD (via Foreflight in my case) for FBO info.  (c) Take a look at Skyvector or AirNav to see if FBOs are listed.  Then I usually call.  I've actually found that about 1/5 of my stops are at locations where you just pay a tiedown fee, but before they go home at night, they'll pull your plane in their hangar if the weather is threatening, and only charge you the hangar fee for the nights they do.  (Discussed in advance, obviously.)

Comment: I have amended my answer based on several comments to show hangar space more likely available than I insinuated.  I haven't done a whole lot of GA overnights and thought hangaring overnight was a rare, expensive, and usually unnecessary luxury.